# How to detect and delete messages with curses

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am working on anti-cussing for my discord bot, and am wondering if there is an easier/better way of doing it rather than doing individual `client.on("message", ...)` listeners.
Here is my code for it, any help would be appreciated.

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.includes('cuss')) { //"cuss" is used for an example
    message.channel.send('Deleted Message');
    message.delete(3000);
    message.member.kick('Offensive Cussing');
  }
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with your approach exactly?

Comment: i am planning on making if for more than one word and i thought there might be a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more than one case (or word) you would use the [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method. You define an array for cusswords and check if some of these are in the message via .includes.

```
const cussWords = ['cuss1', 'cuss2', 'cuss3'];
if (cussWords.some(word => message.content.includes(word))) {
  // do something if a cussword was found
}
```